# How to write sql query to fetch assigned data and processed data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have users and leads assigned to him. 
If user add any followup on lead means that lead is processed.

There are three table,
user : user listing
lead: lead with user id(whom it is assigned)
followup : if processed then one or more entry

I want to generate output like

```
User Lead  Processes Pending
Ram   10      7        3
```

I created sql fiddel for this ,How to find followup count out of assigned leads

```
SELECT user.u_name, count(leads.id), count(follwoup.lead_id) FROM leads left join user On leads.user_id = user.id left join follwoup On follwoup.user_id = user.id group by user.id, follwoup.user_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e00c3/2

Out of group by lead id, if any id is found in followup table means it is processed

Comment: Are yo using SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag your question appropriately.